# Why can I do "cmd & ; cmd2" in zsh but not bash?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, background-process

Why can I do this in zsh:

```
zsh$ sleep 5 &; echo foo
[1] 14742
foo
```

but not in bash?

```
bash$ sleep 5 &; echo foo
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Is there any way to do the equivalent in bash?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't normally use `zsh`, but this seems to be equivalent:

```
sleep 5 & echo foo
```

It also works in `zsh`.

I checked zsh documentation and don't see any special meaning to the combination `&;`. This seems to be just a background command followed by an empty command, which gets ignored. `bash`, on the other hand, doesn't allow empty commands; you get the same error if you type:

```
; echo foo
```

Comment: The documentation would be here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists -- I suppose the key phrase is "a sequence of **one** or more pipelines" (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to spawn a subshell for the background process:

```
bash$ (sleep 5 &); echo foo
```

But I'm not sure if it's strictly equivalent in the sense you are looking for.